# Basic Python loop question - problem reading a list from a text file

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to read a list of items from a text file and format with square brackets and separators like this: ['item1','item2', .... 'last_item']  but I'm having trouble with the beginning and end item for which I always get: ...,'last_item','],  so I do not want the last ,' to be there.

In python I've write:

```
out_list = "['"
for line in open(file_in):  
    out_list += line                #append the item to the list
    out_accession_list += "','"     #add the separator
out_accession_list += "]"           #add the final closed bracket
return out_list
```

I realize that this is a basic loop question, but I can't think of the best way to do it.  Should I use a try final statement, should it be a while loop, or should I count the number of lines first and then use a loop with a range?

Help much appreciated.

Thanks, 
John

Comment: Why do you have so many variables?  Why `out_list` and `out_accession_list`?  Why so many variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read in all your lines and use the `string.join()` method to join them together.

```
lines = open(file_in).readlines()

out_list = "['" + "','".join(lines) + "']"
```

Additionally, `join()` can take any sequence, so reading the lines isn't necessary.  The above code can be simplified as:

```
out_list = "['" + "','".join(open(file_in)) + "']"
```

Comment: True, however, I wanted to be verbose to illustrate things better.

Comment: Your one-liner doesn't strip the end-of-lines: `"['item1\n','item2\n','item3\n']"`.

Comment: You're right, but the example gives enough guidance that the OP should be able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
out_list = []
for line in open(file_in):
    out_list.append("'" + line + "'")
return "[" + ",".join(out_list) + "]"
```

Comment: Why are you doing all the string building in the append?  Just use "','" as your join string.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, that'd be better.  Soviut has the better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You "right strip" for "," the result before adding the last "]".

e.g. use the `string.rstrip(",")`

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
result = "['"
for line in open(file_in):
    if len(result) > 0:
        result += "','" 
    result += line
result += "']"
return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output format is exactly Python's standard printable representation of a list.  So an easy solution is to read the file, create a list with each line as a string element (stripping the end-of-line of each), and call the Python built-in function [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#repr) to produce a string representation of the list:

```
>>> repr([line.rstrip() for line in open(file_in)])
"['item1', 'item2', 'item3']"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def do(filepath):
    out = []
    for line in open(filepath, 'r'):
        out.append("'" + line.strip() + "'")
    return out.__str__()
```